# How to delete a single row and re-order a table

Tags: sql

I have create a table named profiledetails. Then I set a button and gridview in my form. when I select a row in my gridview and click the delete button, the selected will be deleted and other rows will be re-arranged in corret format. but my code is delete a all records in my table, so what can I change this code to get my output.

```
   Public Class profiledetails
      Dim connenctor = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\vk\Database1.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=''"
      Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
      Dim rd As New ADODB.Recordset

     Private Sub view()
       Dim rds As New ADODB.Recordset
       rds.Open("SELECT * FROM profiledetails", con)
        profiledetailsview.Rows.Clear()
        Do While Not rds.EOF
        profiledetailsview.Rows.Add({rds("ID").Value, rds("name").Value, rds("fathername").Value, rds("age").Value, rds("dob").Value, rds("class").Value, rds("contact").Value})
        rds.MoveNext()
    Loop
    rds.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub DetailsForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.Open(connenctor)
    view()
    profiledetailsview.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I have use the code my table records are displayed on my gridview. Now I m add a delete button in my form. When I select anyone row in my grid and I click the delete button, the selected will be delete in my gridview and my db records. after deleted records the table records will be re-order to correct formation.

i.e..,

```
 **GRID VIEW**

   1 ff kk ss ss 
   2 hh kk ii hh
   3 ss hh jj dd
   4 x  y   z  s
   5 rr tt yy hh
   6 rt  rt rt rt
```

now I am select a second row in my gridview and delete it.
the table will be displayed in this format.

```
    1 ff kk ss ss 
    3 ss hh jj dd
    4 x  y   z  s
    5 rr tt yy hh
    6 rt  rt rt rt 

after deleted a row. my table will be re-ordered based on my id. Like this,

    1 ff kk ss ss 
    2 ss hh jj dd
    3 x  y   z  s
    4 rr tt yy hh
    5 rt  rt rt rt
```

how to I written a code ,to get this output ...?please say your suggestion and explain how its working.

Comment: Rows in an RDBMS have no order, so the question is meaningless

Comment: oh... ok ,fine.then  let me say how to delete a single row in my table records. what I am selected in gridview.

Comment: Ordering is done with the select query, which you should show us.

Comment: bro ... I have trouble in delete command. i.e., when I select a 3rd record in my gridview. and I m click the del button. it will be delete all records in my table. I think I have done some mistakes in gridview selection. but I can't identify what mistake was done.

Comment: You should give us more information to work with. The query you show deletes only rows with a specific ID, not all rows.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Also, edit your question, don't clarify in comments.

Comment: You say you have trouble in delete command.  So why do you show everything else apart from the delete command?  We need to see the code you are having trouble with (not the code that works)!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,@jonathan willcock. I already solved this problem at myself.